# Why is the "Create alert rule..." missing for this grid?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

Someone else on my team has created a form - for some reason the Grid control does not have the "Create alert rules..." option in it's context menu.

I can't see what the difference is between this grid/form and others that we have created that do have this in their context menu.

Does anybody know why it would be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be missing because the form window type is `Popup` or the form frame style is other than `Standard`. The rules are specified in `\Classes\EventBuildValidAlertFields\validate`:

```
public boolean validate()
{
    ;
    if (!formRun                            ||
        !formDataSource                     ||
        !formDataSource.cursor().TableId    ||
         formRun.design().windowType() == FormWindowType::PopUp ||
         formRun.design().frame()      != FormFrame::Standard
        )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Frame` property was set to dialog. If anyone can tell me why, I might mark them as answer.